# How to properly get data from a d3.js nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I am currently trying to visualise some data from a rather large array. My outcome is that I would like a multi-line chart.

My array is in the form of CSV to be better handled by D3.js.

My data looked something like this:

category,date,frequency <-- column headers
shopping,23/7/90,9
dating,23/3/96,3

I wanted to be able to handle each category for my multi-line chart individually so decided to map my data into another array which is what's below:

[Console.log(DataNest)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2hwA.png)

My problem now is I don't know how to retrieve the information to create my chart lines?

My code here:

```
var dataNest = d3.nest()
.key(function(d) {return d.category;})
.entries(data_out);

dataNest.forEach(function(d,i) {

var line = d3.line() 
.x(d3.values(dataNest).map(function(d) { return d.date; }).filter(function(key) { return key !== "date"; }))
.y(d3.values(dataNest).map(function(d) { return d.frequency; }).filter(function(key) { return key !== "frequency"; }))
;

  chartGroup.append('path').attr('d',line(d));


          });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that if you're using a CSV or a TSV file your data needs to be in a format like this:

```
category,date,frequency
shopping,23/7/90,9
shopping,28/7/90,9
shopping,27/7/90,9
shopping,23/8/90,9
shopping,23/9/90,9
```

As opposed to this:

```
category,date,frequency shopping,23/7/90,9
category,date,frequency shopping,28/7/90,9
category,date,frequency shopping,27/7/90,9
category,date,frequency shopping,23/8/90,9
category,date,frequency shopping,23/9/90,9
```

Once in the correct format, you can then you can reference the data after you import the CSV as d.category, d.date, etc.

Here is a good example of a great multi-series line chart using a TSV: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback. My apologies but this is down to me being bad with formatting questions on SOF. I'll ammend my question adequately but that is how I am displaying my data originally but I have nested it later as per the photo in my question. That is my data format now.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Well, I'm not able to help with the nested array functions as I'v never gone that route before.  All I can add is that I'm not sure you need to do that extra step if you don't want to.  You can pull each individual category, and the related data, out of your data set as you map the data (if you so chose). Anyways, sorry I couldn't be of more assistance.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll have a look into circumventing that particular step.